# Sci-fi Story Cop riding flying giant genetically engineered birds

Tags: story-identification, novel

It is a Science fiction novel.

Set in Earth's future where giant genetically engineered birds are used as flying vehicles. If I remember correctly, it is due to end of fossil fuels.

The main character is a cop or detective. Police fly on birds of prey. Civilians have ride more mundane species of giant birds, such as song birds.

I read this in paperback between 1992 and 1998.

The Cover had giant falcon or other bird of prey with a police light bar on it.

Here is another person looking for the same novel: http://askville.amazon.com/scifi-book-future-genetic-engineering-policemen-flying-giant-birds/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=85705895

Comment: The battle for the abbreviation IIRC ! x)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like it could be the [Organic Future](http://www.fantasticfiction.co.uk/e/thomas-a-easton/sparrowhawk.htm) Series by Thomas Easton from the early 1990s. Specifically book 1, Sparrowhawk. An excerpt description is below in which a Detective is riding his gengineered Sparrowhawk, while civilians are riding other types of birds.

Description is as follows along with a book cover:

> First volume of the "Organic Future" series. The genetic engineers aren't about to stop with genetically modified food. It won't be long before they're playing with houses and vehicles too, and someone is trying to kill gengineer Emily Gilman! The Chickadee at the bird feeder is the size of a Piper Cub, a Sparrow airliner is gobbling Buggies on the highway, a Mack truck is lunging across the sidewalk, and **detective Bernie Fischer is flying his modified Sparrowhawk to the rescue**.

[image]

Comment: Well done sir. Been looking for this book for more then a few few years.